# How do I read an array of parcelable objects that has objects that are instances of subclasses?

Tags: java, android, arrays, parcelable, serializable

I have a `Parcelable` class `Board` with an array of `Parcelable` objects of type `Square` (the superclass). The array contains objects of type `SnakeSquare` (a subclass) and `LadderSquare` (another subclass) as well.

`Square` implements `Parcelable`. 
`SnakeSquare` and `LadderSquare` extend Square, and override `writeToParcel` and have their own constructors with a `Parcel in` parameter.

My problem is that when I try to read the array of Square objects, it does not cast any of the objects to SnakeSquares and LadderSquares. This is what I've tried so far:

```
public Board(Parcel in) {
    board = new Square[100];

    Object[] temp = in.readArray(Square.class.getClassLoader());

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        if(temp[i] instanceof SnakeSquare)
            board[i] = (SnakeSquare) temp[i];
        else if(temp[i] instanceof LadderSquare)
            board[i] = (LadderSquare) temp[i];
        else
            board[i] = (Square) temp[i];

    }

}
```

However, it doesn't work because none of the elements in temp are instances of SnakeSquare or LadderSquare. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is Square an abstract class?

Comment: No. There are instances of Square within the array as well. The array may have multiple instances of Square, SnakeSquare and LadderSquare.

Answer (score 0):

As long as SnakeSquare and LadderSquare both inherit from Square you should be able to store them in the same array. Have you tried adding them to an ArrayList? I know that I have definitely done something similar when using java's ArrayList data structure.
Below is the example of something similar that I have done. In the code below, BiasNode inherits from InputNode and I am able to store them in the same list. I ran the tests to make sure that everything worked as expected for me and it did. When I check the list, I see a list with both BiasNodes and Input Nodes.

Try using an ArrayList and see what happens.

```
protected ArrayList<InputNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<InputNode>();


public void initializeNodes(int numberOfNodes, boolean addBiasNode)
{
    BiasNode biasNode = new BiasNode(1.0);
    if(addBiasNode)
    {
        nodeList.add(biasNode);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfNodes;i++)
    {
        InputNode newNode = new InputNode();
        nodeList.add(newNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to change here

`Object[] temp = in.readArray(Square.class.getClassLoader());`

`Square.class.getClassLoader()` you are using the base class here, you cant cast a `baseClass` instance to a `childClass` instance, but you can do viceversa.

Comment: This wouldn't work because I have two subclasses, so if I changed it to `LadderSquare.class.getClassLoader()`, I wouldn't be able to cast squares to `SnakeSquares`